# vuejs3 - use a component multiple time

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I'm using vue-3

I am not familiar with vuejs and I am a newbie developer.

**Situation**

I developed a component that I want to use as a child of several parent component.

**Problem**

The child component is displayed only on the last route in the array of routes (here => /custom-object)
[image: component not displayed]
[image: component displayed]

**Questions**

How can i use a component multiple times?
The child component sends data to the parent component so each parent must receive the data independently

**Here my code**

parent component 1

```
<template>
    <input type="text" v-model="translateLabel" />
    <router-view @translate="objectCustom"></router-view>
    <button @click.prevent="upload">upload</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "CustomObject",

    data() {
        return {
            Translations: {},
            translateLabel: "",
        };
    },
    methods: {
        objectCustom(payload) {
            this.Translations = payload;
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

parent component 2 (very similare to parent 1 but the final export will be different)

```
<template>
    <router-view @translate="objectCustom"></router-view>
    <button @click.prevent="upload">upload</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "CustomObject",

    data() {
        return {
            Translations: {},
        };
    },
    methods: {
        objectCustom(payload) {
            this.Translations = payload;
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

index.js (router)

```
import Dashboard from "@/components/Dashboard.vue";
import Translations from "@/components/Translations.vue";
import CustomObject from "@/components/CustomObject.vue";

const routes = [
    {
        path: "/dashboard",
        name: "Dashboard",
        component: Dashboard,

        children: [
            {
                path: "",
                name: "Translations",
                component: Translations,
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        path: "/custom-object",
        name: "CustomObject",
        component: CustomObject,
        children: [
            {
                path: "",
                name: "Translations",
                component: Translations,
            },
        ],
    },
];

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes,
});

export default router;
```

Thank you for your time and help

Comment: Your code looks ok except one thing that may cause the problem - `name` of all routes should be unique across whole router, not just one particular "level". Now you have 2 routes with the same name "Translations"

Comment: thanks !! it's that... i use the same component so i just copy/paste...